# Processing array in Javascript from HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying to pass an array to a Javascript function via the following:

In the controller, I have:

```
@data = [{date: '2014-08-17'}, {date: '2014-08-20'}].to_json
```

In the view, I have:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, nil, :data => {:values => @data } ) %>
```

In the javascript, I have;

```
var eventsList = $('#default').attr('data-values')
```

The values gets passed in, but its recognized as a string rather than an array. How can I get JS to read the eventsList variable as an array instead of as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are JSON encoding it when you set the `data-values`, so you need to decode it on the client.

```
var eventsList = JSON.parse($('#default').attr('data-values'));
```